# При нажатии на button,цифра в input меняет значение

Tags: javascript

```
<p>Верных ответов</p> <input> <button id="math">+</button>
<button id="">-</button>
```

Нужно сделать так,чтобы при нажатии на + в строке input было 1,при повторном нажатии на + цифра росла дальше. Если нажимать на - росла вниз.

Comment: "росла вниз"  - +1!

Comment: нужен именно код ,чтобы я его вставил и провери как работает,я не выкупаю как его сделать.

Comment: "я не выкупаю" - "купать" - в смысле "мыть"?

Comment: Нет,в смысле не понимать.

Comment: Такого в русском языке нет.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var count = 0;
var countEl = document.getElementById("count");
function plus(){
    count++;
    countEl.value = count;
}
function minus(){
    count--;
    countEl.value = count;
}
```

```html
<div id="input_div"><p>Верных ответов</p>
    <input type="text" size="25" value="0" id="count">
    <input type="button" value="-" id="moins" onclick="minus()">
    <input type="button" value="+" id="plus" onclick="plus()">
</div>
```

Comment: Не работает в VS studio